# If there a way to make vsftpd allow one user to access root directory, while other users get redirected to their home directory?

Tags: linux, ftp, vsftpd

I'm running Raspbian Lite on a Raspberry Pi 2. I'm trying to have `vsftpd` set up with one user called `admin` to have root access for FTP, while all other users (such as `filetransfer`) get redirected to their home directory. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I gather you're using vsftpd's `chroot_local_user` setting to keep users within their home directories. If that's enabled, you can use the `chroot_list_file` setting to pass a file containing the users you *don't* want to be locked in their home directories.

You can find out more on the [vsftpd manual page](https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd/vsftpd_conf.html).

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried that and it doesn't seem to work. Maybe I formatted the list file wrong? What I put in the vsftpd.config file was "chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list". In the chroot_list file itself I simply put the name of the user, ```filetransfer```.

Comment: Note that when `chroot_local_user` is enabled, `chroot_list_file` works opposite from how it would normally work. If it's enabled, you'll need to put `admin` in the `chroot_list_file` rather than `filetransfer`